# Renaming all text files in a directory

Tags: powershell

I altered some code for powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt  | ForEach-Object { # Loop over files of interest
  $newName = (Get-Content $_.FullName -Head 1)[-1] # Extract 1st line
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName     # Rename input file
}
```

It is supposed to take each text file in a directory, and rename it to the first line of the file.

```
Rename-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
At line:3 char:8
+   $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName     # Rename input file
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Rename-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

But it gives me that error.

Comment: Have you tried to output what's in the variable `$newName` to see what's actually in it?

Comment: Have you thought of appending the `-WhatIf` option to your last line and reading the output. It should show you what the failing command would be.

Comment: My individual files only have one line in them.  So, it's giving me the last letter of the line, in this test case it was a space.  I changed it to _, and it renames the file to the underscore, but it does not change the line to the entire line.  So, it's treating the line as a string of letters.

Comment: By using `[-1]` you select the last character of the string, so...

Comment: Try `$newName = @(Get-Content $_.FullName -Head 1)[-1]`.  Check whether `$newname` meets rules of [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) (or its equivalent for your OS if you are not on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(Get-Content $_.FullName -First 1)` instead of `(Get-Content $_.FullName -Head 1)[-1]`

`-First` has been introduced in PowerShell 3.0.